# MirrorMaker2 is not able to replicate new partitions added to an existing topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I configured MirrorMaker2 and able replicate topics and and offsets into the destination cluster.

However I added new partitions to a topic in the source cluster and the new partitions are not getting replicated to the destination cluster.

Not sure if the new partitions are handled by MirrorMaker2 or the feature is not supported.

Comment: It should be able to. I've tested this feature in production.

Answer (score 0):

Below properties are responsible for topic properties refreshment.

Make sure it should be enable.

```
refresh.topics.enabled=true
refresh.topics.interval.seconds = 1
```